# Setting style dynamically in a for loop

Tags: angular

I have a condition in my html template that loops through an object and create a list of items. I have studied `[NgClass]` because I need to set the class of a row based on a condition of that particular item.  So my understanding and testing shows that `NgClass` is set once based on a variable. I want it to check during every loop if `true/false`. So basically I want 
`<div [ngClass]="{'redclass': {{hour.enoughrest}}}">` However this of course do not work. Any ideas? I have feeling the solution is obvious but I am at loss.

Comment: So you want to apply a certain classes based on something only if a 'something else' is true?

Comment: Remove interpolation from `{{hour.enoughrest}}`

Comment: `<div [ngClass]="{'redclass': hour.enoughrest}">`

Comment: correct but it is different for of course everytime the loop executes

Comment: Thank you so much!! I understand now and it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible with ngClass. See if example helps.

```
e<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="folios">
    <tr *ngIf="item.shares >0" [ngClass]="{'table-success': item.gainPercent >5,'table-danger': item.gainPercent <-5}">e
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this format:

```
 [ngClass]="{'yourClassName': condition}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the class based on a condition, then try this:

```
<div [class.redclass]="hour.enoughrest">
</div
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to change class dynamically.

```
<div [ngClass]="{'redclass': hour.enoughrest}">
```

Or

```
[class.redclass]="hour.enoughrest"
```

Or if you want to add class based on condition

```
<div [className]="condition ? 'example-class' : 'other-class'"></div>
```

In addition to that you can change NgStyle dynamically and update style as bellow if you want to do style changes.

```
<p [ngStyle] = “{backgroundColor : getColor() }” >

in .ts file
getColor() {
  return this.serverStatus === ‘online’? ‘green’: ‘red’;
}
```